# Selenium keeps a cache? Why my javascript isn't loaded in tests?

Tags: javascript, django, selenium, caching, django-staticfiles

I have a more complicate question but I'm trying to isolate the problem to avoid confusion.

I'm testing a page using selenium. In this page there are two javascript external scripts. If you go there manually the page is working correctly but using selenium one of the javascript isn't loaded:

```
The script from “http://localhost:55234/static/js/common.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
2 add-name
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:55234/static/js/common.js”.
```

Checking the source (right click => view page source) gives me correctly the template with this two lines (and the others, off course):

```
[...] 
<!-- load global javascript -->
    <script type='text/javascript' src="/static/js/common.js"></script>
<!-- load app javascript -->
  <script type='text/javascript' src="/static/lists/js/lists.js"></script>
[...]
```

the src are clickable. Cliking the first one reload the source page without the line three and four, so without this lines:

```
<!-- load app javascript -->
  <script type='text/javascript' src="/static/lists/js/lists.js"></script>
```

Clicking the second one (`lists.js`) gives the javascript code. But! But this code looks an (very) old version of my code. Many days old (isn't too long to be cached?). At that time all the code was in one javascript file (`lists.js`) and the other one (`common.js`) didn't existed so this can explain why isn't loaded.

Why is that? How can I update this code? If I go manually in the page I can find the real updated code.

Also can be useful to know that in my browser I recently selected 'Disable cache' in the Network tab (press F12 with firefox) and 'Disable HTTP cache (...)' in the setting just to avoid these problems. In the page opened by selenium these options are both unchecked. I tried to check both (using a breakpoint()) and reload the page but nothing changed.

I repeat, maybe the cause of this is somewhere else and there many other thing to say but I think is better to keeps things as simple as possible and open other questions when I need. Now, any of this make any sense? why my script isn't updated in days (I prefer to do not empty the cache, if possible)?

I found this code to delete the cache, should I try? It look right?

```
def setUp(self):
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("browser.cache.disk.enable", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.cache.memory.enable", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.cache.offline.enable", False)
    profile.set_preference("network.http.use-cache", False)
    self.browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

Here some code:

My template `base.html`:

```
[...]
<head>
  [...]
  <!-- load global javascript -->
  <script type='text/javascript' src="{% static '/js/common.js' %}"></script>
  <!-- load app javascript -->
  {% block script %}{% endblock %}
[...]
```

my template list.html

```
{% block script %}
  <script type='text/javascript' src="{% static 'lists/js/lists.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

where `common.js` is in `myproject/static/js/common.js`, while `lists.js` is in `myproject/lists/static/lists/js/lists.js`. I call both with `{% static` but it should be correct.

My `test.py`:

```
class NameFormSeleniumTest(LiveServerTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(2)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_form_can_save_a_name(self):
    # some code
    # english = ...
    self.browser.get(self.live_server_url + '/lists/add-name/')
    Select(self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_namelanguage')).\
        select_by_value(str(english.id))
    # ...
    breakpoint()
    form = NameForm({'nametype': nome.id, 'gender': maschio.id,
                     'name': 'Remo', 'namelanguage': english.id,
                     'usato': 0})
    print(form.errors)
    form.save()
```

The error the test gives is (in the line `form = ...`):

```
ValueError: The Name could not be created because the data didn't validate.
```

and `form.error` is:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>nametype<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

but with `breakpoint()` I see the javascript function to add options to the field isn't found, the field stay empty so `Select()` don't select nothing, and the form gives the error.

Thank you for your help

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the browser cache. It looks like the local web server is not returning JavaScript files with the `text/html` mime type when it needs to be `text/javascript`. Check the server configuration to make sure mime types are configured correctly for .js files.

Comment: Unless you are setting Selenium to use a certain profile each time, there will be a fresh cache for every run.  (Which is a great test case!)  It sounds like your manual methods are the ones pulling from cache.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I'm using the django server (manage.py runserver) and it works if I go there manually (I mean navigating with the browser like final users will do). It can be the problem is elsewhere but why I'm seeing the old javascript file? from where it come? It do not exist anymore on my pc (well, maybe in some old git repositoire)

Comment: @pcalkins no, I'm not setting profiles for selenium. What do you mean with the last phrase? Sorry but I'm newbie, I don't understand which can be my 'manual methods'. I have more test files, and even in this test file I have more classes but I don't think to be pulling nothing from the cache (and I don't know how to do). In the code I skipped in this class I just create the objects to popolate the form.

Comment: I add, I had the same load script problem in another test and it wasn't for the server but for some error in the code: if the code isn't right selenium doesn't load the scripts and gives that MIME error (well offcourse there can be other causes). Unluckly I don't remember which code gives me the problem in that occasion, probabily the test code. I'm not sure to can call the form in that way using selenium

Comment: you said, "manually the page is working correctly" That could be a cache issue.  Fresh machine it may not be working correctly.

Comment: ah, ok, now it's clear. I don't think so (and certanly I hope it's not) because is many days I have this problem. I have changed the code many times and it's using the new code

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#testing):

> When running tests that use actual HTTP requests instead of the built-in testing client (i.e. when using the built-in LiveServerTestCase) the static assets need to be served along the rest of the content so the test environment reproduces the real one as faithfully as possible, but LiveServerTestCase has only very basic static file-serving functionality: It doesn’t know about the finders feature of the staticfiles application and assumes the static content has already been collected under STATIC_ROOT.
>
> Because of this, staticfiles ships its own
>   django.contrib.staticfiles.testing.StaticLiveServerTestCase, a
>   subclass of the built-in one that has the ability to transparently
>   serve all the assets during execution of these tests in a way very
>   similar to what we get at development time with DEBUG = True, i.e.
>   without having to collect them using collectstatic first.

So it was loading an old version of my javascript script. Like you can read the solution is to use `StaticLiveServerTestCase` instead of `LiveServerTestCase`.